# Trace / Debug app.config file reads / access operations

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, debugging, app-config

Is there a mechanism (or config file setting) that will trace read operations against a .NET config file?

Background: I'm working on a SOAP test client application and there's one point where it's complaining about not finding the endpoint element and contract details in the configuration file.  There are 9 services, 8 are working fine.  The naming of the problem service is complicated with spelling errors (service name, wsdl port name...)  I'm starting to suspect that parts of the .NET framework use convention rather than direct configuration to locating parts of the binding configuration.  I think I have the name mutated correctly in the various places but when making the connection it still errors.

After all that, what would help is if I could get a trace output as the program (framework) reads through the configuration file.  It would be easy at that point to see what specifically is miss-spelled or where it is my mistake.

It's almost impossible to search for this topic, all the hits along the lines of "debugging config file" return links for adding logging to a config file or configuration management of an app build.

Comment: Is this WCF? Sounds like you need to turn on WCF trace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: And if this is 4.0, WCF will use a default endpoint and binding if it can't find the one you specify. It is quietly noted in the Systems.Diagnostics trace, but it doesn't throw an exception. (Some WCF config problems do cause exceptions, tho)

Comment: Good idea on the WCF trace.  Turned it on and set the tracing aka SwitchValue to All but I'm not getting any new information.  I see the error but with no additional detail.

Comment: Ok, copy your System.ServiceModel section into the question after removing as much extraneous stuff as possible. Post the exact error message(s).

Comment: I can post the other stuff but what I was really looking for was a way to trace the read access of the configuration at a low level.  This seems to be something that might come in handy for later fun and excitement.  Regardless, I'll get an edited version of the ServiceModel section in the post.  Thanks.

Comment: If the WCF people didn't write the trace, then it isn't there. Most trace says "this line of code executed and this was the state at that point", I suppose you could almost get that by step-debugging through the Reference Source code, e.g. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ but that looks like a lot of effort (prolly require a custom host, say in a console, so you could set the initial break point)